# MS Access - Selecting via an aggregate function

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following table. I would like to do two things:
I would like to select all of the rows for all of the People who have more than one Active Entry.

```
PersonName  Address Active  DateUpdated
Adam    Paris   False   09/08/2018
Adam    Dubai   True    17/02/2018
Brendan New York    False   17/02/2018
John    Dublin  True    17/02/2018
John    London  True    09/02/2018
Mike    Miami   False   10/02/2018
Mike    Singapore   False   01/02/2018
Mike    New York    True    01/03/2018
Susan   Los Angeles True    19/02/2018
Susan   Las Vegas   True    17/01/2018
Zara    Berlin  True    05/09/2018
Zara    Madrid  True    12/07/2018
Zara    Houston False   12/09/2018
```

The query:

```
select PersonName,Count(PersonName)
from tempTableTest where Active=True
group by PersonName
```

Gives

```
PersonName  Expr1001
Adam    1
John    2
Mike    1
Susan   2
Zara    2
```

So my resulting table should have all of the rows where PersonName=John, Susan, or Zara (because each of these have more than 1 entry where Active=True). And I would expect it to look like this-

```
PersonName  Address DateUpdated Active
John    London  09/02/2018  True
John    Dublin  17/02/2018  True
Susan   Las Vegas   17/01/2018  True
Susan   Los Angeles 19/02/2018  True
Zara    Berlin  05/09/2018  True
Zara    Madrid  12/07/2018  True
Zara    Houston 12/09/2018  False
```

I would also like to Update Active=False where DateUpdated<>Max(DateUpdated) if that makes sense.
So For John, the row with 09/02/2018 should be set to False (because there is a 17/02/2018)
For Susan 17/01/2018 row should be set to False
And Zara the 05/09/2018 and 12/07/2018 Should be set to False.

Can anybody help? (Would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!).

Comment: oh no the table has not come out How I would expect here. Maybe I can repost it

Comment: Wow thanks a lot all, that was really fast and helpful, and very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try joining to a subquery which restricts to only the matching names having more than one active entry:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tempTableTest t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT PersonName
    FROM tempTableTest
    WHERE Active = True
    GROUP BY PersonName
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2
    ON t1.PersonName = t2.PersonName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `EXISTS` clause to test if specific conditions exist:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tempTableTest t
WHERE EXISTS(
      SELECT 1 
      FROM tempTableTest s 
      WHERE s.Active=True AND s.PersonName = t.PersonName
      GROUP BY PersonName 
      HAVING Count(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tempTableTest t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM tempTableTest t1 
              WHERE t1.PersonName = t.PersonName AND t1.Active = True AND t1.Address <> t.Address
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an update query.

```
UPDATE 
    t52293469 AS T 
SET 
    T.Active = False, T.PersonName = "a", T.DateUpdated = Now()
WHERE 
(
    ((T.Active)=True) 
    AND ((Exists (SELECT 1 
                  FROM t52293469 t1 
                  WHERE t1.PersonName = t.PersonName AND t1.Active = True AND t1.DateUpdated >t.DateUpdated
    ))=True)
);
```

That'll update John, Susan & Zara

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works apart from the fact it should Set both of Zara's TRUE values to false (Note that Zara's most recent entry is already False, so all Values should be set to False). In other words, the update should set everything older than the Max(DateUpdated) for each User to False grouped by Username... if that makes sense..

Comment: UPDATE 
    tempTableTest AS T 
SET 
    T.Active = False, T.DateUpdated = Now()
WHERE 
(
   
     Exists (SELECT 1 
                  FROM tempTableTest t1 
                  WHERE t1.PersonName = t.PersonName AND t1.DateUpdated >t.DateUpdated
)
    =True)